# Python - Trying to write a script that tests an http interface

Tags: python, testing, curl

ers,

I'm still getting to grips with the Python basics..

My current requirement is to develop a Python script that will test the availabilty of web-based interfaces of mulitple devices (e.g. where you may have to enter "http://192.168.0.2:9876" via a web browser), this does not have to be over complicated.

I'm trying to convert from the simple bash curl command, as originally I had something like the following in a bash script:

```
    date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%N"`
    curl -s --connect-timeout 1 ${ip} -o /dev/null
    test=$?
    if [[ $test == 0 ]] ;then
            echo "${date}:webping - Web Page Up for ${ip}" >> $log
    else
            echo "${date}:webping - Web Page Down for ${ip}" >> $log
    fi
```

which worked for the original concept, but I was looking to have something similar in python. the output can vary, within reason... anyone have any pointers on where to start.

P.S I have looked at some other questions on here, but they appear to give false-positives, where the interface has been "taken down" (i.e. I stopped the service) and it still gives a status code of 200.

EDIT: Below is the code I have tried.

```
for url in ["http://www.google.co.uk", "http://192.168.0.2:8000"]:
    try:
            connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            print connection.getcode()
            connection.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print "none"
```

CORRECTION: I get the following results...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1173, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1148, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I would prefer not to see the python error output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the Python code you have tried, what you got when you ran it, and what you expected. "Convert this script to language X", is not a real question for SO.

Comment: @jordanm, sorry see edit above for code. I would expect the restult to be different when the web interface is unavailable (i.e. down because the service has stopped or a fault/error).

Comment: If there is nothing accepting the connection on the port, an exception should be thrown. A quick test on my machine throws: `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> `. You are not catching urllib2.URLError, is it not throwing an exception?

Comment: also it doesn't have to be redirected to a log, STDOUT would be fine for this example

Comment: @jordanm, when I put in a false address/port combo it does return an error like yours, but when I kill the service it still shows "200"

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the service has really been killed? It's hard to see what would give a 200 response other than an actually-working server that your code actually connected to. (Unless there's a proxy in the way, but that doesn't seem at all likely in your situation.)

Comment: What happens if you point a web browser at the same URL after the service is allegedly stopped?

Comment: OK used the "urllib2.URLError" from jordanm's comment above and it returns "none" instead of the python errors

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, I thought I had killed the service... apparently it's because of my lack of concentration (...tiredness...) and killed the wrong service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html for a Python module providing the facilities you need with a nice friendly API. In this instance you'd do something along these lines:

```
import requests
...
try:
  r = requests.get(url, timeout=1)
  ok = (r.status_code // 100) == 2
except:
  ok = False

# now use the value of ok
```

though I don't know whether the particular test I've used there (success means a 2xx response) is exactly what you want.

Comment: I was looking to use this on multiple systems, can I use "requests" module without installing it? ... As I say i'm still learning. :)

Comment: No, you can't use the requests module without installing it. If you want something that doesn't depend on anything beyond what comes with Python, you'll need the `urllib2` module (which is part of Python's standard library). Your code will be more portable but uglier.

Comment: OK thanks. The content on the site does look interesting, and will bear it in mind for more static installations.